# correct jQuery syntax for checking input is checked on previous quiz in a series

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, radio-button

I am trying to get the value of checked or unchecked for the previous question in a quiz. Trying to find all the skipped questions basically.

```
$('li.quiz:eq(' + (slideIndex - 1) +  ')') //gets last question
```

Not sure what the syntax should be but something like this is my intention:

```
if ( $('li.quiz:eq(' + (slideIndex - 1) +  ')')  &&  $('li.quiz:eq(' + (slideCount - 1) +  ')input:radio:checked') ) {
   console.log('this question answered');
} else{
   console.log('this question not answered');
}
```

Comment: If you'd like to get value the sintax is: $(".selector").val()

Comment: 1: if you want the last question, simply do `li.quiz:last`. 2: `$('li.quiz:eq(' + (slideCount - 1) +  ')input:radio:checked')` will always be true since it return a jQuery object. Check the length instead.

Comment: Forget my first point, realized what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I go by your pseudo code, it would be:

```
var elem = $('li.quiz').eq(slideIndex - 1);
if(elem.length && elem.is(':checked')){
  // do somethign   
}
```

jQuery returns `[]` if nothing is found so it would always evaluate to `true`.

Also, you can just use `.is(':checked')` to check if it is checked or not.

Comment: elem is not a checkbox

Comment: That's not what i meant, currently `elem` is an element that contain inputs

Comment: Or wait... is it? I don't know actually, forget it!

Comment: @Amit, elem doesn't get the check though. Trying different things based on all of the comments to check for checked. Tried since but didn't work:
if(elem.length && elem.find('input:radio').prop('checked');

Comment: @bklynM you aren't being clear enough. Show your html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get answered and skipped with the following. Thanks.

```
var prevQ = $('li.quiz:eq(' + (slideIndex - 1) +  ')');
var isChecked = prevQ.find('input:radio[name=ans]').is(':checked');

if (prevQ.length && isChecked) {
   console.log('this question was answered');
} else{
   console.log('this question was not');
}
```